# Jquery loop table from n to n row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table as below:

```html
<table>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td>Group 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 2 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 5 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 5 item 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Whenever I click on any row  I add a class to each row (e.g. selection). If I click on any row which has a class called group then I want to add/remove a class to all other rows (if any) in that group

e.g. If I click on first row which has class called group then I should add another class to row 2,3 and 4 and they belong to row 1 (group 1).

so loop in the rows from current row until group class is found again (e.g. row 5)

can I loop through table from n to n row?

Comment: and where is your jQuery for this ? please share that also

Comment: this content seems like you want to do something for child element where your closest `tr` which not have a group behave like a  child.If this then you have to use another element type ie list, navbar etc.

Comment: I don't see why you would put a grouped list in a table? Sounds more like a list structure to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  use `nextUntil()` method to select the next elements until you reach the next `tr.group`

see here > [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

You also need to get the `groupIndex` so you can add class accordingly to the selected `tr`

And of course add/remove the selection and group1,2,3,4,5 classes when clicking on other elements. I added some colors ( you can see them in css ) for example purposes

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  var groupIndex = $(this).closest('table').find('.group').index(this) + 1
  $(".selection").removeClass("selection")

  $(this).addClass("selection") //for example
  if ($(this).hasClass("group")) {
    $(this).siblings().not(".group").removeClass()
    $(this).nextUntil(".group").addClass("group" + groupIndex + "")
  }
});
```

```css
.group1 {
  color: red;
}

.group2 {
  color: blue;
}

.group5 {
  color: yellow;
}

.selection {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td>Group 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Group 1 item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 2 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group'>
    <td> group 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 5 item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> group 5 item 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function of JQuery to change class of sub-group elements.

```js
$(".group").on("click",function(e){
 
  $(this).siblings(".group").removeClass("selected-header")
  $(this).addClass("selected-header")

  $(this).siblings().not(".group").removeClass("selected")
  $(this).nextUntil(".group").addClass("selected")
})
```

```css
.selected-header{
  color : green
}

.selected{
  color : blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='group'> <td>Group 1 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Group 1 item 1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Group 1 item 2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Group 1 item 3</td> </tr>
<tr class='group'> <td> group 2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> group 2 item 1</td> </tr>
<tr class='group'> <td> group 3</td> </tr>
<tr class='group'> <td> group 4</td> </tr>
<tr class='group'> <td> group 5</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> group 5 item 1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> group 5 item 2</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works as i needed. Unfortunately above solution also works so I selected that. thanks for very quick solution